# Pass Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Contents into PrintDocument

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Visual Studio 2010, Visual Basic.NET

I have a WebBrowser Control(wbImages) on a form and I need to allow the user to print the contents of that WebBrowser Control.  If I use wbImages.Print(), it will print the document, but only uses the default printer.  So I would like to open the print dialog to allow the user to change the printer.  Unfortunately I do not know how to convert the contents of wbImages to a PrintDocument.

Here is what I currently have.

```
Private Sub PrintToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, _ 
        e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintToolStripMenuItem.Click

    'I need to get the wbImages into pdocImages
    'pdocImages = ConvertPrintDoc(wbImages)

    pdImages.Document = pdocImages
    pdImages.PrinterSettings = pdocImages.PrinterSettings
    pdImages.AllowSomePages = True
    If pdImages.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        pdocImages.PrinterSettings = pdImages.PrinterSettings

        If imageUrl.IndexOf(".jpg") <> -1 Or imageUrl.IndexOf(".gif") <> -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Image has been sent to the printer.")
            wbImages.Print()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Table has been sent to the printer.")
            wbImages.Print()
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Not possible.  You have to use the [WebBrowser.Print()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method.

Comment: So the user will never be able to change the printer when printing the web page?

Comment: Use WebBrowser.ShowPrintDialog()

Comment: Aww man, I so happy you posted this!!!!  Works like a charm, thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

This method will draw the currently visible content in the web browser into a bitmap, which  will then print:

```
Private Sub PrintToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, _ e As System.EventArgs)  Handles PrintToolStripMenuItem.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(TakeSreenShot(WebBrowser1), 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg)
        g.CopyFromScreen(Control.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(Control.Width, Control.Height))
    End Using
    Return tmpImg
End Function
```

Obviously it will only print what is currently visible, which is a drawback but I don't know of any other way of doing it. 
Hope this helps.